# Break array into chunks and prepend each row with a static element

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
$list = array('item1','item2','item3','item4','item5','item6');
```

i need to take this array and break it into smaller arrays within 1 array for the csv.  Each small array needs to have '999999' at index 0, followed by the next two items in the `$list` array.  So the final result would be like this:

```
$newList = array(
    array(999999, "item1" , "item2"),
    array(999999, "item3" , "item4"),
    array(999999, "item5" , "item6")
);
```

The original list array may contain up to 100 values at sometimes.  What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different way of doing it, please see the comment as to where you place your additional elements to be prepended (you could add a second array into the merge at the end to add elements after the 2 list items too!)

See here for working example: http://codepad.org/hucpT5Yo

```
<?php
$list = array('item1','item2','item3','item4','item5','item6');
$list_chunks = array_chunk($list,2);

$list_chunks2 = array_map(
                     create_function(
                        '$x',  
                        'return array_merge(array(
                           /* This array is prepended to the second, 
                              add as many elements as you like */
                           999999,
                           "another element to add",
                           483274832
                            ), 
                        $x);'), 
                     $list_chunks);

print_r($list_chunks2);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$idx = 0;
$newarray = array();
$temparray = array('999999');
foreach($oldarray as $value) {
   $temparray[] = $value;
   if ((++$idx % 2)) == 0) {
       $newarray[] = $temparray;
       $temparray = array('999999');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Break your flat array into an array 2-element rows with `array_chunk()`, then call `array_merge()` on each row with the static value `999999` nested in an array and nominated as the first argument.

The modern syntax for the chunk-n-merge technique demonstrated by @Lee looks like this:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2dD6j))

```
$list = ['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5','item6'];

var_export(
    array_map(fn($row) => array_merge([999999], $row), array_chunk($list, 2))
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 999999,
    1 => 'item1',
    2 => 'item2',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 999999,
    1 => 'item3',
    2 => 'item4',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 999999,
    1 => 'item5',
    2 => 'item6',
  ),
)
```